# Building custom form for QGIS in Python plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I want a custom "QGIS 2.14.6 Essen" layer edit form in my own python plugin.

I use `layer.setEditForm( NODE_ui_path )` and `layer.setEditFormInit('NODE.formOpen')`

Function `NODE.formOpen` does not work!

MyPlugin is in `~\.qgis2\python\plugins\MyPlugin`

Ui Form is in `~\.qgis2\python\plugins\MyPlugin\NODE.ui`

formOpen is in `~\.qgis2\python\plugins\MyPlugin\NODE.py`

Answer (score 3):

Solved by :

```
layer.editFormConfig().setInitCodeSource(1)
layer.editFormConfig().setInitFilePath(python_file_path)
layer.setEditForm(ui_file_path)
layer.setEditFormInit('formOpen')
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

**IN QGIS 3.0**

```
config = layer.editFormConfig()
config.setInitCodeSource(1)
config.setUiForm("ui_file.ui")
config.setInitFilePath("py_file.py")
config.setInitFunction("method_name")
layer.setEditFormConfig(config)
```